# Android push notifications limit (C2DM)

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

As stated [here](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/?hl=es-419&csw=1) there is a limit, the error code exists:

QuotaExceeded — *Too many messages sent by the sender. Retry after a while.*

My question; does anyone knows the real meaning (values) of "Too many messages" and "Retry after a while"?

Somewhere it says 200k per day, but I can get this error if I send 30 messages really quick (30 in 2 o 3 seconds to the same device).

Note: C2DM is deprecated, I know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your messages are most likely being throttled. Use the collapse key to group messages and send them out in batches. This is GCM documentation but should be relevant to what you are doing.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#throttling

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, I was aware of the use of collapse_key, but I'm trying to limit the ammount of messages, and for that I need an idea of the messages/second/device ratio.

Comment: According to this site, it's 1 message per 3 minutes (20 per hour). http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-c2dm/126tzbngtc/message-per-device-quota

Comment: Well, isn't that ratio a bit too small? Unfortunately there is no link to the oficial documentation, it looks like an observation over a certain behavior.